# css dropdown menu addition for navbar

Tags: css, list, menu, html-lists

I am trying to add the dropdown menu for my menu, but it doesnt seem to show when I hover over it. Thanks for the upcoming support.

This is my code in a jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nbh2e15y/2/

the css:

```
#nav {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #585858;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

#searchbar input[type=text] { 

    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
    width: 230px;


}

#searchbar input[type="submit"] {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1abc9c;
    border: 1px solid #12ab8d;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4px 15px;
}

#searchbar { margin-right:10px; }



#nav ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#nav ul li {
line-height:50px;
float:left;
}

#nav ul li a {
line-height:50px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:400;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
background-color:none repeat scroll 0 0 #585858;
display:block;
padding:0 20px;
}


#nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    #nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
        position: relative;
    }
        #nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            #nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
            }


#nav ul li a:hover {
background-color:#333;
}

#nav ul li a.active {
background-color:#333;
}
#nav ul li active {
background-color:red;
}

li.active {
    float: right !important;
}
li.active_messages {
    float: right;
}
```

and the html code:

```
<div id="nav"> 

<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="categories.php">Categories</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

<li><a href="about.php">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="my_profile.php">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="my_parts.php">My Listings</a></li>
<li><a href="verification.php">Get Verified!</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
<li class="active">
<div id="searchbar">  
<form action="search.php" method="get">
<input type="text" hidden="" value="product/search" name="route">
<input type="text" required="" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</div></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add

```
#nav ul>li:hover>ul {
  top:initial;
}
```

to your CSS, then when the `li` is moused over, the `ul` will be restored to its original view, so the dropdown will "appear".

When you do this, you'll notice some shifting.  Your CSS is in need of some improvement for readability, but this shifting will be because something along the way is not taken out of the flow of the page, but that's another question.

Comment: Yeah why is it shifting @Jeremy, also Leo, could you post your code too?

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

CSS code:

```
#nav {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #585858;
border-radius: 3px;
height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 0;
}

#searchbar input[type=text] { 
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 25px;
padding: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
width: 230px;
}
#searchbar input[type="submit"] {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1abc9c;
border: 1px solid #12ab8d;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 4px 15px;
}
#searchbar { margin-right:10px; }

#nav ul {
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
#nav ul li {
line-height:50px;
float:left;
}
#nav ul li a {
line-height:50px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:400;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
background-color:none repeat scroll 0 0 #585858;
display:block;
padding:0 20px;
}
#nav ul ul {
background: #5f6975; 
border-radius: 0px;
padding: 0;
display:none;
position: absolute;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
position:absolute;
}
#nav ul ul li a {
color: #fff;
background: #5f6975; 
}   
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
background: #4b545f;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
background-color:#333;
}
#nav ul li a.active {
background-color:#333;
}
#nav ul li active {
background-color:red;
}
li.active {
    float: right !important;
}
li.active_messages {
    float: right;
}
```